# How can I encrypt the config value for db-password on Keycloak 22?

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I just could not find anything on the internet that can solve our problem.

We are moving from the Wildfly distribution of Keycloak to the Quarkus distribution. Everything has been great except that we cannot find a way to hide the value for the db-password config entry.

With the Wildfly distribution, we could use the Elytron Credential Store, I am not sure if I am missing something, but I cannot find anything similar that I can use for the Quarkus distribution of Keycloak.

Keycloak will not be running on a container, using environment variables is not an option.

How can I hide/encrypt the config values?

I have tried creating a bash script to start Keycloak and passing the db-password value as an argument, and then compiling this script to a binary file to hide the passed value. This option works but it feels like too much of a work-around and I thing our client might freak out.

Thank you :-)